# maven configuration plugin issue

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven, automation

IM using eclipse java 2021-03-R and java jdk1.8.0  as i tried to configure the java project to maven Im getting error and im unable to clear. Pls help. Im trying to learn selenium automation.Please help.

oreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.2: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.3.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2.pom. Error code 501, HTTPS Required

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to use a Maven version over a decade old, and from before the mandatory usage of https of more than 2 years (https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334)?

Comment: Eclipse is out of date, the used maven-compiler-plugin is extremely old and as already mentioned http usage instead of https!